# routing double rendering in not matching case reactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi all I've got a redux router problem ...

I defined those two routes:

```
<Route path="/*" component={() => (<Error/>)}/>
<Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Logins foo={"test"} loginHandler={this.props.loginHandler}/>)}/>
```

Both routes are displayed ...

the * should only be shown If no one other matches

Comment: What is the Router version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Route-Switch to make a NoMatch page. Like this:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router'

<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Logins foo={"test"} loginHandler={this.props.loginHandler}/>)}/>
  <Route component={() => (<Error/>)}/>
</Switch>
```